# Cannot assign to 'textBoxSettingsMethod' because it is a 'method group'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress

I have reviewed about 20 plus pages on the web regarding this error.  I have been unable to find a solution to this.  I know why the error is occurring but cannot figure out how to fix this. :

I just need to assign an action to my action, but these actions must have an incoming parameter of type string.  Any ideas are greatly appreciated as I have been struggling with this for quite some time.

```
public class CommonDemoHelper
{
    static Action<TextBoxSettings> textBoxSettingsMethod(string txtBoxName);
    static Action<DateEditSettings> dateEditSettingsMethod;
    static Action<LabelSettings> labelSettingsMethod;
    static Action<LabelSettings> wideLabelSettingsMethod;
    static Action<SpinEditSettings> spinEditSettingsMethod;
    static Action<MemoSettings> memoSettingsMethod;

    public static Action<TextBoxSettings> TextBoxSettingsMethod(string txtBoxName)
    {
        get
        {

            if (textBoxSettingsMethod(txtBoxName) == null)
                //Getting error below cannot assign to method group
                textBoxSettingsMethod = CreateTextBoxSettingsMethod(txtBoxName);
            return textBoxSettingsMethod(txtBoxName);
        }
    }

    static Action<TextBoxSettings> CreateTextBoxSettingsMethod(string txtBoxName)
    {
        return settings =>
        {
            settings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "editor";
            settings.ShowModelErrors = true;
            settings.Properties.ValidationSettings.ErrorDisplayMode = ErrorDisplayMode.ImageWithText;
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a method (or delegate) returns a value, it will be a `Func<return_type>`, not an action. If it has input parameters (arguments) then it would be a `Func<arg1,arg2,arg3,return_type>`

```
static Func<string, TextBoxSettings> textBoxSettingsMethod;

public static Func<string, TextBoxSettings> GetTextBoxSettingsMethod(string txtBoxName)
{
    if (textBoxSettingsMethod == null)
        textBoxSettingsMethod = CreateTextBoxSettingsMethod(txtBoxName);
    return textBoxSettingsMethod;
}

static Func<string, TextBoxSettings> CreateTextBoxSettingsMethod(string txtBoxName)
{
    ...
}
```

Here `Func<string, TextBoxSettings>` designates a method that accepts a string parameter (input) and returns a `TextBoxSettings` (output).

Also, since you need an input argument in `TextBoxSettingsMethod` it cannot be a property. I changed it to be a method.

Also I changed the test to make sure that `textBoxSettingsMethod` is not null (not the result is returning when you execute it). The test `textBoxSettingsMethod(txtBoxName) == null` calls the method and tests if the return value of type `TextBoxSettings` is `null`. If you only want to know whether the method is defined, the test should be `textBoxSettingsMethod == null`.

Do not confuse the expression `textBoxSettingsMethod` which **is** the method (or delegate) and `textBoxSettingsMethod(txtBoxName)` which **executes** the method.

---

What is the argument `string txtBoxName` good for? You are not using it. Do you need different methods for different textboxes? It's difficult to say.

---

**UPDATE**

This creates always the same method that returns different settings depending on the textbox name (the argument `string txtBoxName` is not required, only the argument of the lambda expression `tbName` which will require an actual parameter value when called):

```
static Func<string, TextBoxSettings> CreateTextBoxSettingsMethod()
{
    return tbName =>
    {
        TextBoxSettings settings;
        switch (tbName) {
            case "textbox1":
            case "textbox2":
            case "textbox3":
                settings = new TextBoxSettings {
                    TextBoxName = tbName,
                    ControlStyle = "editor",
                    ShowModelErrors = true
                };
                settings.Properties.ValidationSettings.ErrorDisplayMode = ErrorDisplayMode.ImageWithText;
                return settings;
            case "textbox4":
            case "textbox5":
                settings = new TextBoxSettings {
                    TextBoxName = tbName,
                    ControlStyle = "displayer",
                    ShowModelErrors = false
                };
                settings.Properties.ValidationSettings.ErrorDisplayMode = ErrorDisplayMode.TextOnly;
                return settings;
            default:
                return new TextBoxSettings { TextBoxName = tbName };
        }
    };
}
```

---

In contrast, this is a method that creates different methods that return alwas the same settings

```
static Func<string, TextBoxSettings> CreateTextBoxSettingsMethod(string txtBoxName)
{
    switch (txtBoxName) {
        case "textbox1":
        case "textbox2":
        case "textbox3":
            return tbName =>
            {
                var settings = new TextBoxSettings {
                    TextBoxName = tbName,
                    ControlStyle = "editor",
                    ShowModelErrors = true
                };
                settings.Properties.ValidationSettings.ErrorDisplayMode = ErrorDisplayMode.ImageWithText;
                return settings;
            };
        case "textbox4":
        case "textbox5":
            return tbName =>
            {
                var settings = new TextBoxSettings {
                    TextBoxName = tbName,
                    ControlStyle = "displayer",
                    ShowModelErrors = false
                };
                settings.Properties.ValidationSettings.ErrorDisplayMode = ErrorDisplayMode.TextOnly;
                return settings;
            };
        default:
            return tbName => new TextBoxSettings { TextBoxName = tbName };
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE #2**

Maybe you want this

```
static Dictionary<string, Func<string, TextBoxSettings>> textBoxSettingsMethod
    = new Dictionary<string,Func<string,TextBoxSettings>>();

public static Func<string, TextBoxSettings> GetTextBoxSettingsMethod(string txtBoxName)
{
    Func<string, TextBoxSettings> method;
    if (!textBoxSettingsMethod.TryGetValue(txtBoxName, out method)) {
        method = CreateTextBoxSettingsMethod(txtBoxName);
        textBoxSettingsMethod.Add(txtBoxName, method);
    }
    return method;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
Func<string, TextBoxSettings> method;
TextBoxSettings setting;

method = GetTextBoxSettingsMethod("textbox1");
setting = method("textbox1");

// or

setting = GetTextBoxSettingsMethod("textbox1")("textbox1");

// or, if you are sure that all the methods have been assigned

method = textBoxSettingsMethod["textbox1"];
setting = method("textbox1");

// or

setting = textBoxSettingsMethod["textbox1"]("textbox1");
```

But I'm still not sure why you want to create these methods dynamically. A simple method returning  the setting would suffice

```
public static TextBoxSettings GetTextBoxSettings(string txtBoxName)
{
    switch (txtBoxName) {
        // ...
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Essentially, I need that txtBoxName in order to determine which textbox i am receiving and return different settings per the name etc.  I don't see how I can get away with it not being an Action and changing to a Func.

Comment: Yes, but is this argument really necessary in `CreateTextBoxSettingsMethod(string txtBoxName)`? Does this method return different settings creation methods depending on the tb name and do these settings creation methods need this argument again? Should `textBoxSettingsMethod` possibly be a `Dictionary<string,Func<string, TextBoxSettings>>` or just a `Dictionary<string,Func<TextBoxSettings>>`?

Comment: It is necessary specifically there because I will have a switch statement returning different settings per type/name of textboxes.  I need that tb name to get into that specific CreateTextBoxSettingsMethod.  Am I making sense regarding how I am attempting to make this work?

Comment: +1 for now until I get this to work, thanks so much for you help, but even with the fantastic samples you provided I have been unable to get this to work in my scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring `textBoxSettingsMethod` as a method:

```
static Action<TextBoxSettings> textBoxSettingsMethod(string txtBoxName);
```

when it looks like you're trying to define it as a property:

```
static Action<TextBoxSettings> textBoxSettingsMethod;
```

Although since `txtBoxName` is not used in `CreateTextBoxSettingsMethod` it's a little confusing as to what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes, its confusing. The OP seems to have a method that returns a method that returns a method.

Comment: I am attempting to assign an action to an action, but both actions need to have an incoming parameter of type string....

Comment: The main difference is: will `txtBoxName` be used to _define_ the Action, or will `txtBoxName` be evaluated _when the action is run?